# ¿Como puedo extraer con Python datos de un fichero XML con subelementos?

Tags: python, xml

Tengo una web de venta Online y quiero poder extraer datos de los pedidos. EL archivo que obtengo de la web es XML o texto. La idea es pasarlo a CSV para poder trabajarlo con Pandas
He probado mil maneras distintas, con Beautiful Soup, con lxml, con ElementTree, etc, etc, etc.

Los elementos que tienen un nombre único(OrderNumber) no tengo problema. El problema es con los productos(LineItems). Cada pedido tiene un número diferente de producto(Id) de nombre(Name), catidad(Quantity), etc. Consigo extraer todos los productos, pero todos seguidos, sin saber el número de productos que corresponden a cada pedido.

He intentado pasarlo a csv y a un DataFrame directamente y siempre tengo el problema de los productos.

Cualquier ayuda será agradecida profundamente.

El texto XML es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Orders>
  <Shop>
    <GUID>49A44A11-B3C983C3-A1C85211B59D</GUID>
  </Shop>
  <Order>
    <OrderNumber>1089</OrderNumber>
    <CustomerNumber>1028</CustomerNumber>
    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    <Language>es</Language>
    <Locale>es_ES</Locale>
    <TaxArea>EU</TaxArea>
    <TaxModel>gross</TaxModel>
    <GrandTotal>27.37</GrandTotal>
    <TotalBeforeTax>23.59</TotalBeforeTax>
    <TotalTax>3.78</TotalTax>
    <Addresses>
      <BillingAddress>
        <FirstName>Pedro</FirstName>
        <LastName>Lopez</LastName>
        <Gender>1</Gender>
        <Street>Mayor, n17</Street>
        <Zipcode>10932</Zipcode>
        <State>Burgos</State>
        <City>Burgos</City>
        <EMail>correo@hotmail.com</EMail>
        <Phone>3585859</Phone>
        <Country>ES</Country>
      </BillingAddress>
      <ShippingAddress>
        <FirstName>Pedro</FirstName>
        <LastName>Lopez</LastName>
        <Street>Mayor, n17</Street>
        <Zipcode>10932</Zipcode>
        <State>Burgos</State>
        <City>Burgos</City>
        <EMail>correo@hotmail.com</EMail>
        <Phone>3585859</Phone>
        <Country>ES</Country>
      </ShippingAddress>
    </Addresses>
    <LineItems>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>POT-16MMLIN-B1K</Id>
        <Name>Potenciometro Lineal 16mm Alpha</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>1.55</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>1.55</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>K-FLUTED-0002</Id>
        <Name>Botones de control enflautados.</Name>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>0.75</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>1.50</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
        <VariationString>Capacitancia: 0.010uF, Voltaje: 100V
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>ENC-1590WB</Id>
        <Name>Caja Aluminio Hammond 1590B</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>7.55</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>7.55</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>J-JACKNE-MON</Id>
        <Name>Jack Mono Neutrik</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>1.25</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>1.25</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>J-JACKNE-ST</Id>
        <Name>Jack Stereo Neutrik</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>1.58</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>1.58</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>J-DC2.1-INT</Id>
        <Name>Jack DC 2.1mm</Name>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>0.55</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>1.10</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>SW-3PDT</Id>
        <Name>Interruptor pie 3PDT</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>5.15</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>5.15</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>POT-16MMLOG-A500K</Id>
        <Name>Potenciometro Logaritmico 16mm Alpha</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>1.65</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>1.65</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItemShipping>
        <TotalPrice>4.86</TotalPrice>
        <Name>Certificado Nacional / Paquete Azul</Name>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
        <TaxComponent>
          <TaxRate>0.21</TaxRate>
          <Value>4.86</Value>
        </TaxComponent>
      </LineItemShipping>
      <LineItemPayment>
        <Id>PayPal Standard</Id>
        <Name>PayPal</Name>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItemPayment>
      <LineItemPaymentDiscount>
        <TotalPrice>1.18</TotalPrice>
      </LineItemPaymentDiscount>
    </LineItems>
    <CreationDate>2010-03-15T01:07:29</CreationDate>
    <ViewedOn>2010-03-16T12:11:05</ViewedOn>
    <DispatchedOn>2010-03-16T12:11:51</DispatchedOn>
    <PaidOn>2010-03-15T01:10:07</PaidOn>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderNumber>1088</OrderNumber>
    <CustomerNumber>1136</CustomerNumber>
    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    <Language>es</Language>
    <Locale>es_ES</Locale>
    <TaxArea>EU</TaxArea>
    <TaxModel>gross</TaxModel>
    <GrandTotal>12.90</GrandTotal>
    <TotalBeforeTax>11.12</TotalBeforeTax>
    <TotalTax>1.78</TotalTax>
    <Addresses>
      <BillingAddress>
        <FirstName>Luis</FirstName>
        <LastName>Lopes</LastName>
        <Gender>1</Gender>
        <Street>c/Juan Encina</Street>
        <Zipcode>56012</Zipcode>
        <State>Madrid</State>
        <City>Madrid</City>
        <EMail>correo2@gmail.com</EMail>
        <Phone>54223422</Phone>
        <PhoneCell>23334342</PhoneCell>
        <Country>ES</Country>
      </BillingAddress>
    </Addresses>
    <LineItems>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>S-PINSTRIP-SIL10</Id>
        <Name>Tira de pines en lÃ­nea SIL</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>0.75</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>0.75</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>ACC-BATT9V-TW-T</Id>
        <Name>Conector Pila 9V Tipo-T</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>0.12</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>0.12</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>SW-3PDT</Id>
        <Name>Interruptor pie 3PDT</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>5.15</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>5.15</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>LED-BEZEL5MM</Id>
        <Name>ZÃ³calo portaled 5mm</Name>
        <Quantity>3</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>0.75</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>2.25</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>R-CARBON1/4-2-1M</Id>
        <Name>Resistencia de PelÃ­cula de Carbon Xicon 1/4W, 1%</Name>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>0.12</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>0.24</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>R-CARBON1/4-2-68K</Id>
        <Name>Resistencia de PelÃ­cula de Carbon Xicon 1/4W, 1%</Name>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>0.12</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>0.12</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItem>
        <Id>R-METAL1/4-1.2K</Id>
        <Name>Resistencia PelÃ­cula MetÃ¡lica Xicon 1/4W, 1%</Name>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice>0.13</UnitPrice>
        <Discount>0.00</Discount>
        <TotalPrice>0.65</TotalPrice>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItem>
      <LineItemShipping>
        <TotalPrice>3.62</TotalPrice>
        <Name>Certificado Nacional / Paquete Azul</Name>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
        <TaxComponent>
          <TaxRate>0.21</TaxRate>
          <Value>3.62</Value>
        </TaxComponent>
      </LineItemShipping>
      <LineItemPayment>
        <Id>CashInAdvance</Id>
        <TotalPrice>0.00</TotalPrice>
        <Name>Transferencia Bancaria</Name>
        <TaxRate>0.16</TaxRate>
      </LineItemPayment>
    </LineItems>
    <CreationDate>2010-03-11T17:33:36</CreationDate>
    <ViewedOn>2010-03-12T18:51:45</ViewedOn>
    <InProcessOn>2010-03-12T18:53:02</InProcessOn>
    <DispatchedOn>2010-03-16T12:11:51</DispatchedOn>
    <PaidOn>2010-03-12T18:53:02</PaidOn>
  </Order>
</Orders>
```

EL DataFrame sería algo así:

> OrderNumber CustomerNumber FirstName Country Id_Producto   Quantity CreationDate

0   1089        1028          Pedro     ES   POT-16MMLIN-B1K    1     2010-03-15

1   None        None          None     None  K-FLUTED-0002      2        None

2   None        None          None     None  ENC-1590WB         1        None

3   1088        1136          Luis      ES   S-PINSTRIP-SIL10   1     2010-03-11

4   None        None          None     None  ACC-BATT9V-TW-T    1        None

5   None        None          None     None  SW-3PDT            1        None

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado csv o pandas DataFrame que quieres obtener?

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Disculpa por el "DataFrame" que he puesto. Es la primera pregunta que hago y todavía no se como funciona bien .

Comment: Te he puesto un resúmen. Me interesarian más columnas. No sé si el enfoque de lo que quiero hacer es el correcto (saber cuantos productos ha comprado un cliente por ejemplo) o habría una mejor forma, pero no he sido capaz de dar con la solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta el hecho de que hay:

- Campos referentes a todo el pedido y campos propios de cada item
- Campos que solo aparecen en unos items (es decir, que no son obligatorios para todos los items)
- Campos diferentes con el mismo nombre que se identifican en función de la etiqueta padre

Y dado también que (supongo) no se puede asumir el orden de cada elemento en el XML, lo que yo haría sería lo siguiente.

No es una solución especialmente óptima supongo. Estoy seguro de que las hay mejores, pero la forma más "limpia" que me viene a la mente es algo así:

#### Lectura de datos XML

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
from numpy import arange # Si usas numpy, sustituye la llamada a arange por np.arange

# Lectura de datos como sea que la hagas: aqui un ejemplo
archivo = 'xml\\file.xml'

# Lectura de datos de archivo para simular el ejemplo como string
#with open(archivo, 'r') as f:
#    xml_text = f.read().splitlines()
#xml_text = ''.join(xml_text).encode('utf-8')

# Si recibes xml como un string:
root = etree.fromstring(xml_text)

# Si lees xml desde archivo
root = etree.parse(archivo).getroot()
```

#### Procesamiento de datos

En este caso, lo que se me ocurre es procesar cada `Order` por separado (en lugar de recorrer todo el archivo nodo a nodo con `root.iter()`, que puede resultar en un jaleo de código y múltiples condicionales).

De forma que la función `processOrder()` procesa un nodo `Order` y devuelve un `DataFrame` ya creado para luego concatenarlos y rehacer el índice.

```
dataframes = ()
for e in root.iterchildren():
    # Guarda el GUID si fuera necesario
    if e.tag == 'Shop':
        shop_guid = e.getchildren()[0].text
    # Procesa cada order por separado
    elif e.tag == 'Order':
        df_order = processOrder(e)
        dataframes += (df_order,)

df_total = pd.concat(dataframes)
df_total.index = arange(len(df_total))
```

La función `processOrder`, la haría procesando primero los items en un `DataFrame` (una linea por item) y luego el resto de datos del pedido (una única linea). Y trataría las direcciones aparte renombrando sus campos para diferenciarlos ya que coinciden con otros campos del documento.

Después se concatenan los `DataFrame`s y dado que el `DataFrame` resultante corresponde a un solo pedido, se pueden imputar datos del pedido (no de los items) al resto de filas sin preocuparse de que se propage la información a campos de otro pedido.

> Esto permite pasar de esto:

```
|    | Id                | Name                                 | Quantity | OrderNumber | CustomerNumber |
|----|-------------------|--------------------------------------|----------|-------------|----------------|
| 0  | POT-16MMLIN-B1K   | Potenciometro Lineal 16mm Alpha      | 1        | 1089        | 1028           |
| 1  | K-FLUTED-0002     | Botones de control enflautados.      | 2        | NaN         | NaN            |
| 2  | ENC-1590WB        | Caja Aluminio Hammond 1590B          | 1        | NaN         | NaN            |
| 3  | J-JACKNE-MON      | Jack Mono Neutrik                    | 1        | NaN         | NaN            |
| 4  | J-JACKNE-ST       | Jack Stereo Neutrik                  | 1        | NaN         | NaN            |
| 5  | J-DC2.1-INT       | Jack DC 2.1mm                        | 2        | NaN         | NaN            |
| 6  | SW-3PDT           | Interruptor pie 3PDT                 | 1        | NaN         | NaN            |
| 7  | POT-16MMLOG-A500K | Potenciometro Logaritmico 16mm Alpha | 1        | NaN         | NaN            |
| 8  | S-PINSTRIP-SIL10  | Tira de pines en lÃƒÂ­nea SIL         | 1        | 1088        | 1136           |
| 9  | ACC-BATT9V-TW-T   | Conector Pila 9V Tipo-T              | 1        | NaN         | NaN            |
| 10 | SW-3PDT           | Interruptor pie 3PDT                 | 1        | NaN         | NaN            |
| 11 | LED-BEZEL5MM      | ZÃƒÂ³calo portaled 5mm               | 3        | NaN         | NaN            |
```

> A esto:

```
|    | Id                | Name                                 | Quantity | OrderNumber | CustomerNumber |
|----|-------------------|--------------------------------------|----------|-------------|----------------|
| 0  | POT-16MMLIN-B1K   | Potenciometro Lineal 16mm Alpha      | 1        | 1089        | 1028           |
| 1  | K-FLUTED-0002     | Botones de control enflautados.      | 2        | 1089        | 1028           |
| 2  | ENC-1590WB        | Caja Aluminio Hammond 1590B          | 1        | 1089        | 1028           |
| 3  | J-JACKNE-MON      | Jack Mono Neutrik                    | 1        | 1089        | 1028           |
| 4  | J-JACKNE-ST       | Jack Stereo Neutrik                  | 1        | 1089        | 1028           |
| 5  | J-DC2.1-INT       | Jack DC 2.1mm                        | 2        | 1089        | 1028           |
| 6  | SW-3PDT           | Interruptor pie 3PDT                 | 1        | 1089        | 1028           |
| 7  | POT-16MMLOG-A500K | Potenciometro Logaritmico 16mm Alpha | 1        | 1089        | 1028           |
| 8  | S-PINSTRIP-SIL10  | Tira de pines en lÃƒÂ­nea SIL         | 1        | 1088        | 1136           |
| 9  | ACC-BATT9V-TW-T   | Conector Pila 9V Tipo-T              | 1        | 1088        | 1136           |
| 10 | SW-3PDT           | Interruptor pie 3PDT                 | 1        | 1088        | 1136           |
| 11 | LED-BEZEL5MM      | ZÃƒÂ³calo portaled 5mm               | 3        | 1088        | 1136           |
```

La función `processOrder`:

```
# Seleccion de las columnas que quieres obtener
# (Si quieres todas, elimina las condiciones de cada lista)
item_columns = ['Id', 'Name', 'Quantity']
address_columns = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'EMail', 'Country']
order_columns = ['OrderNumber', 'CustomerNumber', 'TaxArea', 'CreationDate']

def processOrder(order):
    # Extrae los datos de cada item
    items_data = []
    for item in order.findall('.//LineItem'):
        current_item = dict()
        for e in item.iterchildren():
            if e.tag in item_columns:
                current_item[e.tag] = e.text
        items_data.append(current_item)

    # Extrae datos generales de pedido
    order_data = dict()
    for e in order.iterchildren():
        # Salta los datos de item
        if e.tag == 'LineItems':
            continue

        # Addresses: Procesa subcampos editando el nombre para evitar colisiones de nombre
        if e.tag == 'Addresses':
            for address_field in e.iter():
                if len(address_field.getchildren()) == 0 and address_field.tag in address_columns:
                    order_data[address_field.getparent().tag + address_field.tag] = address_field.text
        # Items indivuales del order
        else:
            if e.tag in order_columns:
                order_data[e.tag] = e.text

    # Concatena dataframes: Si se quiere hacer padding es el momento de hacerlo
    pd_items_data = pd.DataFrame(items_data)
    pd_order_data = pd.DataFrame([order_data])
    pd_order = pd.concat((pd_items_data, pd_order_data), axis=1)

    # Descomentar para imputar datos
    # pd_order[pd_order_data.keys()] = pd_order[pd_order_data.keys()].fillna(method='pad')
    return pd_order
```

Espero que te oriente un poco para lo que necesitas.

### Update 1 (09/05/2020)

De cara a un posterior análisis de datos, recomendaría imputar datos para que todos los item tuvieran los datos del pedido (y no solo el primer elemento).
Esto es, descomentar la línea antes del `return` de `processOrder`:

```
pd_order[pd_order_data.keys()] = pd_order[pd_order_data.keys()].fillna(method='pad')
```

Obteniendo:

```
|    | Id                | Name                                              | Quantity | OrderNumber | CustomerNumber | TaxArea | BillingAddressFirstName | BillingAddressLastName | BillingAddressEMail | BillingAddressCountry | ShippingAddressFirstName | ShippingAddressLastName | ShippingAddressEMail | ShippingAddressCountry | CreationDate        |
|----|-------------------|---------------------------------------------------|----------|-------------|----------------|---------|-------------------------|------------------------|---------------------|-----------------------|--------------------------|-------------------------|----------------------|------------------------|---------------------|
| 0  | POT-16MMLIN-B1K   | Potenciometro Lineal 16mm Alpha                   | 1        | 1089        | 1028           | EU      | Pedro                   | Lopez                  | correo@hotmail.com  | ES                    | Pedro                    | Lopez                   | correo@hotmail.com   | ES                     | 2010-03-15T01:07:29 |
| 1  | K-FLUTED-0002     | Botones de control enflautados.                   | 2        | 1089        | 1028           | EU      | Pedro                   | Lopez                  | correo@hotmail.com  | ES                    | Pedro                    | Lopez                   | correo@hotmail.com   | ES                     | 2010-03-15T01:07:29 |
| 2  | ENC-1590WB        | Caja Aluminio Hammond 1590B                       | 1        | 1089        | 1028           | EU      | Pedro                   | Lopez                  | correo@hotmail.com  | ES                    | Pedro                    | Lopez                   | correo@hotmail.com   | ES                     | 2010-03-15T01:07:29 |
| 3  | J-JACKNE-MON      | Jack Mono Neutrik                                 | 1        | 1089        | 1028           | EU      | Pedro                   | Lopez                  | correo@hotmail.com  | ES                    | Pedro                    | Lopez                   | correo@hotmail.com   | ES                     | 2010-03-15T01:07:29 |
| 4  | J-JACKNE-ST       | Jack Stereo Neutrik                               | 1        | 1089        | 1028           | EU      | Pedro                   | Lopez                  | correo@hotmail.com  | ES                    | Pedro                    | Lopez                   | correo@hotmail.com   | ES                     | 2010-03-15T01:07:29 |
| 5  | J-DC2.1-INT       | Jack DC 2.1mm                                     | 2        | 1089        | 1028           | EU      | Pedro                   | Lopez                  | correo@hotmail.com  | ES                    | Pedro                    | Lopez                   | correo@hotmail.com   | ES                     | 2010-03-15T01:07:29 |
| 6  | SW-3PDT           | Interruptor pie 3PDT                              | 1        | 1089        | 1028           | EU      | Pedro                   | Lopez                  | correo@hotmail.com  | ES                    | Pedro                    | Lopez                   | correo@hotmail.com   | ES                     | 2010-03-15T01:07:29 |
| 7  | POT-16MMLOG-A500K | Potenciometro Logaritmico 16mm Alpha              | 1        | 1089        | 1028           | EU      | Pedro                   | Lopez                  | correo@hotmail.com  | ES                    | Pedro                    | Lopez                   | correo@hotmail.com   | ES                     | 2010-03-15T01:07:29 |
| 8  | S-PINSTRIP-SIL10  | Tira de pines en lÃ­nea SIL                        | 1        | 1088        | 1136           | EU      | Luis                    | Lopes                  | correo2@gmail.com   | ES                    | NaN                      | NaN                     | NaN                  | NaN                    | 2010-03-11T17:33:36 |
| 9  | ACC-BATT9V-TW-T   | Conector Pila 9V Tipo-T                           | 1        | 1088        | 1136           | EU      | Luis                    | Lopes                  | correo2@gmail.com   | ES                    | NaN                      | NaN                     | NaN                  | NaN                    | 2010-03-11T17:33:36 |
| 10 | SW-3PDT           | Interruptor pie 3PDT                              | 1        | 1088        | 1136           | EU      | Luis                    | Lopes                  | correo2@gmail.com   | ES                    | NaN                      | NaN                     | NaN                  | NaN                    | 2010-03-11T17:33:36 |
| 11 | LED-BEZEL5MM      | ZÃ³calo portaled 5mm                              | 3        | 1088        | 1136           | EU      | Luis                    | Lopes                  | correo2@gmail.com   | ES                    | NaN                      | NaN                     | NaN                  | NaN                    | 2010-03-11T17:33:36 |
| 12 | R-CARBON1/4-2-1M  | Resistencia de PelÃ­cula de Carbon Xicon 1/4W, 1%  | 2        | 1088        | 1136           | EU      | Luis                    | Lopes                  | correo2@gmail.com   | ES                    | NaN                      | NaN                     | NaN                  | NaN                    | 2010-03-11T17:33:36 |
| 13 | R-CARBON1/4-2-68K | Resistencia de PelÃ­cula de Carbon Xicon 1/4W, 1%  | 1        | 1088        | 1136           | EU      | Luis                    | Lopes                  | correo2@gmail.com   | ES                    | NaN                      | NaN                     | NaN                  | NaN                    | 2010-03-11T17:33:36 |
| 14 | R-METAL1/4-1.2K   | Resistencia PelÃ­cula MetÃ¡lica Xicon 1/4W, 1%     | 5        | 1088        | 1136           | EU      | Luis                    | Lopes                  | correo2@gmail.com   | ES                    | NaN                      | NaN                     | NaN                  | NaN                    | 2010-03-11T17:33:36 |
```

A partir de esto, puedes agrupar con la función `groupby()` en función del valor que te interese, y contar `count()` los elementos de cada grupo.

`count()` te da el número de lineas que tienen valor para cada columna, por lo que asegurate de coger una columna que siempre tenga datos, como `Id`.

Para saber el número de elementos en cada pedido:

```
df_total.groupby('OrderNumber').count()

|             | Id | Name | Quantity | VariationString | CustomerNumber | TaxArea | BillingAddressFirstName | BillingAddressLastName | BillingAddressEMail | BillingAddressCountry | ShippingAddressFirstName | ShippingAddressLastName | ShippingAddressEMail | ShippingAddressCountry | CreationDate |
|-------------|----|------|----------|-----------------|----------------|---------|-------------------------|------------------------|---------------------|-----------------------|--------------------------|-------------------------|----------------------|------------------------|--------------|
| OrderNumber |    |      |          |                 |                |         |                         |                        |                     |                       |                          |                         |                      |                        |              |
| 1088        | 7  | 7    | 7        | 0               | 7              | 7       | 7                       | 7                      | 7                   | 7                     | 0                        | 0                       | 0                    | 0                      | 7            |
| 1089        | 8  | 8    | 8        | 1               | 8              | 8       | 8                       | 8                      | 8                   | 8                     | 8                        | 8                       | 8                    | 8                      | 8            |
```

De forma que:

```
items_por_pedido = df_total.groupby('OrderNumber').count()['Id']
items_por_pedido['1089'] # 8
items_por_pedido['1088'] # 7
```

Comment: El primer bloque for funciona perfectamente. No había caido en la idea de iterar y comprobar con el nombre de la columna. Buena idea. Pero el segundo bloque for no funciona correctamente. Los LineItems los encuentra, pero cuando busca en Addresses si imprimo  Order data me devuelve el diccionario vacio, por lo que no se concatena en el DataFrame

Comment: Luego, otra historia es saber cuantos o que LineItem corresponde con cada OrderNumber o CustomerNumber, por eso no sé si el enfoque que estoy dando es el correcto a la hora de poder analizarlo más tarde. Muchas gracias por tú esfuero

Comment: @Camberano ¿Podrías comprobar que esté todo correcto? A mí me funciona copiando y pegando tal cual la función. Podría ser un tema de versiones aunque lo dudo.
Otra cosa que se me olvidó comentar es que faltaba una etiqueta por cerrar en tu código XML, pero he supuesto que fue un error tipográfico al pasarlo al post, ya que si no el código habría dado error al leer el archivo.

Comment: He actualizado el post en relación a tu segundo comentario. Respecto al primero, asegurate de que indicsa cada campo en la lista correspondiente (`item_columns`, `address_columns`, `order_columns`). Si es un XML diferente, puede que haya algún caso que no esté contemplado en el ejemplo del post.

Comment: Ya funciona. Estudiaré bien el código y a ver que puedo ir haciendo. Mil gracias.